# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API / C# : unknown column x in 'field list'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

Excuse me if the question already exists but i can't find out what is wrong in my code...

I use an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API written in C#. I need to get a resource including comments for that resource.

Here's my resource model:

```
public class Resource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int UpVote { get; set; }
    public int DownVote { get; set; }
    public TypeRessource Type { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RessourceId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my `Comment` model:

```
public class Comment
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePost { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public int RessourceId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

The `dataContext`:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Consultation> Consultations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Favoris> Favoris { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReportedComment> ReportedComments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReportedRessource> ReportedRessources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Voted> Voteds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ZoneGeo> ZoneGeos { get; set; }

    public DataContext()
    {
    }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    // Configurations des tables
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        //Resource//
        builder.Entity<Resource>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Resources");
            entity.HasKey(r => r.Id);
            entity.Property(r=>r.Description).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(r => r.DownVote).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(r => r.UpVote).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(r => r.Type).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(r => r.CreationDate).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(r => r.Title).IsRequired();
            entity.HasMany(r=>r.Comments).WithOne().HasForeignKey(r=>r.RessourceId).IsRequired();
        });

        builder.Entity<Comment>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Comments");
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            entity.Property(c => c.Content).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(c => c.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(c => c.RessourceId).HasColumnName("ResourceId").IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

This is the controller :

```
// GET: api/Resources/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetResource(int id)
{
        try
        {
            var resource = await _context.Resources.Where(r=>r.Id == id).Include(r=>r.Comments).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (resource == null)
            {
                string[] errorList = new string[] { $"La ressource {id} n'a pas été trouvée ou n'existe pas." };
                Response<Resource> responseNotFound = new Response<Resource>(null, $"La ressource {id} n'a pas été trouvée ou n'existe pas.");
                return NotFound(responseNotFound);
            }

            Response<Resource> response = new Response<Resource>(resource, $"La ressource {id} a été trouvée.");
            return Ok(response);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response<Resource> response = new Response<Resource>(null, ex.Message);
            return BadRequest(response);
        }
}
```

And finally what I get

```
{
  "data": null,
  "succeeded": true,
  "errors": null,
  "message": "Unknown column 'c.ResourceId1' in 'field list'"
}
```

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Are you using db code first? Migrations? Please provide DB tables structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `RessourceId` in `Comment` class but finding column `ResourceId`.